# jquery mobile 'non-mobile' option

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am using the detect and redirect using [detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).  i inserted the code in all my pages.  At the footer of all mobile pages I include a link to 'non'mobile' page, which is the root directory(index).  Problem is the detection script always fires up, ending up browsing the same mobile page.  What is the trick and the best way to view non-mobile page on mobile?

thanks.

Comment: Point your link to a page where you set up a session variable, and use it to check it against detection-script's choice.

Comment: @Alan This is legit. It should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Point your link to a page where you set up a session variable, and use it to check it against detection-script's choice.

Answer (score 0):

If your using anchor tag like this:-

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Make sure you disable the ajax:-

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" data-ajax="false">Click</a>
```